# Celery (Django) + RabbitMQ + nodejs server exchange data

Tags: node.js, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have an `Django` project using `Celery` with `RabbitMQ` broker. And now I want to call django (celery) task from `NodeJS` server.

In my `NodeJS` I'm using `amqplib`. Which is allow me to send tasks to `RabbitMQ`:

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'celery';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: true});
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer('What should I write here?'));
  });
});
```

My question is what format celery use? What should I write to Buffer to call celery worker?

For example, in my `CELERY_ROUTES` (django settings) I have `blabla.tasks.add`:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
   ...
   'blabla.tasks.add': 'high-priority',
}
```

how to call this `blabla.tasks.add` function?

I've tried many ways but celery worker giving me error: `Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html here.

Example message format is:

`{
    "id": "4cc7438e-afd4-4f8f-a2f3-f46567e7ca77",
    "task": "celery.task.PingTask",
    "args": [],
    "kwargs": {},
    "retries": 0,
    "eta": "2009-11-17T12:30:56.527191"
  }`

So code should be:

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'celery';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: true});
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer('{"id": "this-is-soo-unique-id", "task": "blabla.tasks.add", "args": [1, 2], "kwargs": {}, "retries": 0}'), {
      contentType: 'application/json',
      contentEncoding: 'utf-8',
    });
  });
});
```